# Is this set in 3rd normalized form?

Tags: database-normalization, decomposition, 3nf

The functional dependencies are :

- BCD -> A   (I stated this is a SK since BCD+=ABCDEFG)
- BC -> E    (also SK since BC+=ABCDEFG)
- A -> F (not SK or prime)
- F -> G
- C -> D (not sk or prime)
- A -> G (not sk or prime)

My steps:

1. 1:(A,F),(ABCDEG)
2. (A,F),(C,D),(ABCEG)
3. (A,F),(C,D),(A,G),(ABCE)  (so is this one in 3nf?)

I am only trying to set it to 3nf and not go any further.

Comment: *"I am only trying to set it to 3nf and not go any further. "* Normalization doesn't work that way. Aiming for 2NF might yield relations in 5NF.

Comment: When some FDs hold, other ones (given by Armstrong's axioms) must also hold. You need to follow a 3NF normalizing algorithm as given by some reference. What reference are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you decompose your dependencies, you should convert them into minimal set of functional dependency.

As you  have stated, BCD and BC are both super keys, thus the D in BC is not really needed. Further, between A->F, F->G, A->G you can remove A->G, as that is implied by the the other two(you can't remove F->G, you will lose this dependency).

So the minimal set becomes:
(BC->AE), (A->F), (F->G), (C->D)

Now you can decompose into 4 relations: (ABCE),(AF),(FG),(CD).

This will be in the 3NF.

Comment: BCD and BC are both superkeys. Only BC is a candidate key.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.